# Dist upgrade broke the kiosk mode

Tags: vnc, lxde, chromium, raspbian-jessie

I was using RPi in kiosk mode with chromium browser set up via following config files:

`/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`

```
@xset s off
@xset -dpms
@xset s noblank

@chromium --kiosk --disable-ipv6 --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-java --disable-restore-session-state --disable-sync --disable-transate --disk-cache-size=1 --media-cache-size=1 "https://example.com"
```

`/etc/xdg/autostart/x11vnc.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Name=X11VNC
Comment=
Exec=x11vnc -forever -usepw -display :0 -ultrafilexfer
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
Hidden=false
```

Then I did the dist-upgrade from Wheezy to Jessie (which among others introduces systemd). Now my config for kiosk mode seem to be ignored. The lightdm normally starts into the login prompt. I can normally log-in start the chromium and start the x11vnc.

What config changes do I have to do to start with the chromium in kiosk mode when graphical regime starts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same problem, and found a solution : 
copy your `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` to  `/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`

(you should of course adjust the directory to match your users's home, if you're not using the "pi" user)

Comment: Yes, but why so? I thought that the one in `/etc` is the global, which is used when the one in `~` is not defined.